How to enter hovered diagnostic?
If I want to see or copy whole diagnostics, I have to click it with my mouse. Is there any way to enter hovered diagnostics automatically after hovering diagnostics? enter image description here
I donnot find any solutions for this problem.

(TLDR - try pressing the same key once again)
This depends on which UI front-end you use for LSP/vim diagnostics, but most of them are wrappers of vim.diagnostic.open_float() and have similar functionality and key bindings. When you call said function for the first time, it opens the floating window, but when you call it once again, it moves the cursor into the window. If you want it to enter the window automatically, you just need to call it twice.
So, in your case, try pressing the same key combination as the one that opens floating window diagnostic. This a common practice in vim/neovim ecosystem that the function opening floating window, moves the cursor into said window, when called once again.
